# How to filter Foreign Key relations on Django serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, django-orm, django-serializer

How to generate left outer join query using reverse foreign key relation and map it to the nested serializer? I want to filter result on multiple foreign keys.

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_name = models.CharField(max_length=1024) 

class Paper(models.Model):    
    paper_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Answer(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField()
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answer_questions')
    paper_id = models.ForeignKey(Paper, related_name='answer_papers')
 class Meta:
    unique_together = ("question_id", "paper_id")
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PaperSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):        
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'paper_name')
        model = Paper            

class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'score', 'question_id', 'paper_id')
        model = Answer    

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer_questions = AnswerSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True)    
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'question_name', 'answer_questions')
        model = Question
```

**views.py**

```
class QuestionList(generics.ListAPIView):      
    def get_queryset(self):
        paper_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        queryset = Question.objects.filter(answer_questions__paper_id=paper_id, answer_questions__question_id=F('id'))
        return queryset

    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

**My url is**
    localhost/papers/1/questions/

**Expected output:**
 (1) List of all questions with answer object for **corresponding question_id and paper_id only (single answer object)** embedded in it.
 (2) List should include all questions irrespective of they are answered or not (in case of question not answered, question with empty answer object should be returned) i.e. left outer join

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question_id": 1,
        "answer_questions": [
            {
                "id": 24,
                "score": 5,
                "question_id": 1,
                "paper_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 27,
                "score": 8,
                "question_id": 1,
                "paper_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 28,
                "score": 6,
                "question_id": 1,
                "paper_id": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Current Output:**
(1) I am getting multiple answer objects for particular question_id **including all paper_id**s. i.e. For question_id = 1 and paper_id = 2, My output shows questions with answer objects for question_id = 1 **not filtering on paper_id**.
(2) Only answered questions (as query is inner join query)

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question_id": 1,
        "answer_questions": [
            {
                "id": 24,
                "score": 5,
                "question_id": 1,
                "paper_id": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If it's not a good way to implement, kindly suggest better way to optimize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll get desired output if you slightly change the `get_quesyset()` method.

```
class QuestionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.all()

    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

When you access the **`QuestionList list api`** you will get the output as follows

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "question_name": "qus-1",
        "answer_questions": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "score": 50,
                "question_id": 4,
                "paper_id": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "score": 10,
                "question_id": 4,
                "paper_id": 5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "question_name": "qus-2",
        "answer_questions": []
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "question_name": "que-3",
        "answer_questions": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "score": 342,
                "question_id": 6,
                "paper_id": 4
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

#### Update-1

Change your serializer as below

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer_questions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_answer_questions(self, question):
        paper_id = self.context['view'].kwargs.get('paper_id')
        return AnswerSerializer(question.answer_questions.filter(paper_id=paper_id), many=True).data

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'question_name', 'answer_questions')
        model = Question
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But for each question in a paper, I want answer object for that question in the same paper only. (paper_id can be fetched from URL)

Comment: updated the answer (`Update-1`). Adjust your `urls` so that it could pass to the `view`

Comment: Result only gives answered questions. I want all questions irrespective of they are answered or not. (in case of question not answered, question with empty answer object should be returned) i.e. left outer join

Comment: I do getting the desired output [Refer this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GWa6.jpg), Is that wrong?

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. I had applied filter on Question object in views. Thank you so much for your help.